# What are the new changes in Apache POI 3.9 ? Memory leakage issue in 3.9?

Tags: version, apache-poi, package, xssf

In Apache POI 3.9 version release they are telling the memory leak and creating temp file is fixed (bug : 53493). But how to use that? Is there any changes for the importing packages in 3.9 version compared to 3.8? If the changes occur, then what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [change log](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) for Apache POI is [available online](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html). To see the changes between 3.8 and 3.9, look between [here](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9) and [here](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.8-FINAL)

Unless otherwise detailed in the release notes included in the download, you should be fine to just drop the new jars in, in place of the old ones. Make sure you really remove the old ones though! You get all sorts of odd things going wrong if you have both old and new POI jars on your classpath

Comment: OK.. Now I am using the new jar files, but it shows the memory leakage issue same as in 3.8 version. I tried to retrieve 10000 records from DB and creates Excel file, It took around one hour time to create the file. Is there any new function or new package available in 3.9 version for resolving the memory leakage issue??